# How to Decrypt a given Encrypted .txt file in Python?

Tags: python, encryption

I have given an Encrypted .txt file that has been encrypted using Python. Here is the code that used for Encryption.

```
 file1 = open("plain1.txt","r")
file2 = open("secret1.txt","a")
#print file1.read()
for l in file1.readlines():
  for w in l:
    if ord(w) >= 32 and ord(w) <= 126: 
      t_ord = ord(w) + 17
      if t_ord > 126:
        t_ord = t_ord - 126 + 31
      file2.write(chr(t_ord))
    else:
      file2.write(w)
file1.close()
```

Here is the secret1.txt

> W!'$1%t!$v1r u1%v(v 1+vr$%1rx!1!'$1wr&yv$%1s$!'xy&1w!$&y1! 1&yz%1t! &z v &=1r1 v)1 r&z! =1t! tvz(vu1z 1]zsv$&+=1r u1uvuztr&vu1&!1&yv1"$!"!%z&z! 1&yr&1r}}1~v 1r$v1t$vr&vu1v#'r}?
>   _!)1)v1r$v1v xrxvu1z 1r1x$vr&1tz(z}1)r$=1&v%&z x1)yv&yv$1&yr&1 r&z! =1!$1r +1 r&z! 1%!1t! tvz(vu1r u1%!1uvuztr&vu=1tr 1}! x1v u'$v?1hv1r$v1~v&1! 1r1x$vr&1sr&&}v>wzv}u1!w1&yr&1)r$?1hv1yr(v1t!~v1&!1uvuztr&v1r1"!$&z! 1!w1&yr&1wzv}u=1r%1r1wz r}1$v%&z x1"}rtv1w!$1&y!%v1)y!1yv$v1xr(v1&yvz$1}z(v%1&yr&1&yr&1 r&z! 1~zxy&1}z(v?1Z&1z%1r}&!xv&yv$1wz&&z x1r u1"$!"v$1&yr&1)v1%y!'}u1u!1&yz%?
>   S'&=1z 1r1}r$xv$1%v %v=1)v1tr 1 !&1uvuztr&v1>>1)v1tr 1 !&1t! %vt$r&v1>>1)v1tr 1 !&1yr}}!)1>>1&yz%1x$!' u?1eyv1s$r(v1~v =1}z(z x1r u1uvru=1)y!1%&$'xx}vu1yv$v=1yr(v1t! %vt$r&vu1z&=1wr$1rs!(v1!'$1"!!$1"!)v$1&!1ruu1!$1uv&$rt&?1eyv1)!$}u1)z}}1}z&&}v1 !&v=1 !$1}! x1$v~v~sv$1)yr&1)v1%r+1yv$v=1s'&1z&1tr 1 v(v$1w!$xv&1)yr&1&yv+1uzu1yv$v?1Z&1z%1w!$1'%1&yv1}z(z x=1$r&yv$=1&!1sv1uvuztr&vu1yv$v1&!1&yv1' wz z%yvu1)!$|1)yzty1&yv+1)y!1w!'xy&1yv$v1yr(v1&y'%1wr$1%!1 !s}+1ru(r tvu?1Z&1z%1$r&yv$1w!$1'%1&!1sv1yv$v1uvuztr&vu1&!1&yv1x$vr&1&r%|1$v~rz z x1svw!$v1'%1>>1&yr&1w$!~1&yv%v1y! !$vu1uvru1)v1&r|v1z t$vr%vu1uv(!&z! 1&!1&yr&1tr'%v1w!$1)yzty1&yv+1xr(v1&yv1}r%&1w'}}1~vr%'$v1!w1uv(!&z! 1>>1&yr&1)v1yv$v1yzxy}+1$v%!}(v1&yr&1&yv%v1uvru1%yr}}1 !&1yr(v1uzvu1z 1(rz 1>>1&yr&1&yz%1 r&z! =1' uv$1X!u=1%yr}}1yr(v1r1 v)1sz$&y1!w1w$vvu!~1>>1r u1&yr&1x!(v$ ~v &1!w1&yv1"v!"}v=1s+1&yv1"v!"}v=1w!$1&yv1"v!"}v=1%yr}}1 !&1"v$z%y1w$!~1&yv1vr$&y?

So based on this information. How can I Decrypt the 'secret1.txt' file so that I could find out what was the plain1.txt ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there an RSA private key provided or authentication, then you could decrypt it's meaning but this is just verbage in the `secret1.txt` file, can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I have not provided anything else. Just the above Python code and secret1.txt

Comment: ok this is a simple example of working through encryption/decryption using python, see this [link](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/asymmetric-key-ciphers/rsa-encrypt-decrypt-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Reverse engineer the encryption program.

When a character's ord() is < 32, it doesn't change.

If it's >= 32 and <= 126, they added 17 to it, so just subtract 17. And apply the same kind of logic for the final logic.

Also, you can run your decrypted result back through the encryption program to verify your solution (it should look the same as the secret1.txt)